# Why it doesn't make sense to assign other object to builtin objects, such as document, window?

Tags: javascript

```
<script>
this.document = "xxxx";  // why it doesn't make sense?
console.log(document);   // still show document obj in devtools
</script>
```

I think maybe this be banned by javascript engine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`window.document` is not a writeable property. If you want a local variable named `document` you can do so:

```
(function(){
  var document = 'xxxx';
  console.log(document);
})();
```

and:

```
new function(){
  this.document = 'xxxx';
  console.log(this.document);
};
```

Both will log 'xxxx'

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it makes sense - and *is* allowed, for example you can reassign intristic function `window.alert`.

But in 99% cases you better leave it well enough alone.

Answer (score 1):

Re-assigning built ins yields non-portable behavior.

Library A relies heavily on document.getElementById.  Library B relies on its own custom version, but replaced the getElementById on the document prototype with its own custom version.  Library A breaks.

Therefore, library A, which is designed to work with and is tested against all browsers, won't work.

It's the same argument as global variables.  Built-ins are basically global variables.